# Windows Shell scripting and powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I am completely new to Shell scripting (working on Windows Server 2008 R2), 4 hours back i started understanding it. While searching on SO as well as on Google I found that most of the tutorials/sites talking about Linux/Unix shell scripts.

- Does the script for writing batch file is similar to shell script in Linux/Unix?

My requirement is to fetch some details from a some folders, running SP/SQL Scripts on SQL Server & executing SQL Agent Jobs.

- Is using Powershell is an advantage or learning is limited to windows server configuration/version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Does the script for writing batch file is similar to shell script in Linux/Unix?

No. Batch syntax is completely different from Linux/Unix shell script syntax. Check the homepage of the awesome [Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php) for tutorials on batch.

> - Is using Powershell is an advantage or learning is limited to windows server configuration/version?

Using PowerShell is most likely an advantage. PowerShell is installed by default since Windows Vista/Server 2008, but is also available for [Windows XP and Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929). If you have to decide whether you want to learn batch or PowerShell: go for PowerShell. It's *far* more versatile than batch.

Comment: IMHO there's almost no reason to learn batch anymore. Everything is going to PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me.. I started working on Powershell and those newbies who are reading this comment *It is quite easy, it seems that programming is on the top of .NET framework so if you have .NET knowledge then you can easily give a jump start to it*